# How to add HexViewer to Sublime Text2

Tags: sublimetext2

How do I add the HexViewer to Sublime Text2?  I am [here (https://github.com/facelessuser/HexViewer)](https://github.com/facelessuser/HexViewer) and the instructions say "Download is available in Package Control or you can download or clone directly and drop into your Sublime Text 2 packages directory (plugin folder must be named HexViewer)"   Where/what is Package Control?

And if/when I have installed it successfully, what is the toggle key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control) can be found here.

Take a look at `Default (<Your OS>).sublime-keymap` on the github page for the keymaps.

Comment: You need to add the example keymap from github to /Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Default (<Your OS>).sublime-keymap

Comment: What about the toggle key? I have HexViewer installed. Been googling now and looking at the documentation http://facelessuser.github.io/HexViewer/usage/ for minutes on how to show the HexViewer. How to enable the the HexViewer?

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek You will need to find out what command you are tryinig to execute and use that command in your key binding. You can see what command is being executed by entering `sublime.log_commands(True)` in the ST console.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek i know this is very late to reply to your problem, but just for the sake of others. `Tools > Packages > Hex Viewer > Toggle Hex View` .

Answer (score 2):

Follow this [instruction](http://facelessuser.github.io/HexViewer/installation/)

**1st step:** Ensure Package Control is installed.

**2nd step:** In Sublime Text, press **ctrl + shift + p** (Win, Linux) or **cmd + shift + p** (OSX) to bring up the quick panel and start typing **Package Control: Install Package**.

**3rd step:** Select the command and it will show a list of installable plugins.
Start typing **HexViewer**; when you see it, select it.

**4th step:** Restart to be sure everything is loaded proper.

**5th step:** Enjoy!

Comment: I start typing HexxViewer but it doesn't come up in the list.  Is it still in use as a plugin?