# Decode four-hex-digits in sublime text

Tags: regex, hex, sublimetext

Some lines of a file:

```
2e72 7372 6300 0000 8c04 0000 00e0 1a00
0010 0000 00d0 1a00 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 4000 0040 2e72 656c 6f63 0000
0c00 0000 0000 1b00 0010 0000 00e0 1a00
```

Is there a way to transform it in readable characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You could try a plugin like this: https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3728

I'm sure there are others out there, but this is what I found with a quick Google search. Just look for "hex to ascii plugin sublime" or something like that. Also, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995707/how-to-add-hexviewer-to-sublime-text2) related question.